# Two Buttons with two onclick events are not working

Tags: html, jsp, button, onclick, edit

I want to have Edit and Delete button to delete DB records in one HTML page with JSP. I tried the below code. But only the first button is working ( Whichever I put on the top) and the second one is not working. Could any one help..?

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function edit(regno){
var f=document.form;
f.method="post";
f.action='edit.jsp?regno='+regno;
f.submit();
}
function delete(regno){
var f=document.form;
f.method="post";
f.action='delete.jsp?regno='+regno;
f.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" name="form">
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
<%
Connection conn = null;
int sumcount=0;
Statement st;
try{
Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:mydb1");
String query = "select * from student";
st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
%>
<%
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><input type="button" name="delete"  value="Delete"
onclick="delete(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);"> </td>
<td><input type="button" name="edit"  value="Edit"     
onclick="edit(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);"> </td>
</tr>
<%
}
%> 
<%
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far? In your case, post `edit()` and `delete()` functions. And your business logic too.

Comment: For your information, you need to edit your question to post your updated code.

Comment: Hi Vinoth, Changed the question.. Please look..

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6mGzj/

Below example works fine, you can check in console where form is sended after button is clicked.

```html
<form method='post' id='form'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='button' data-action='delete' data-regno='2' value='delete' /></td>
            <td><input type='button' data-action='edit' data-regno='3' value='edit' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var type = e.target.getAttribute('data-action'),
        regno = e.target.getAttribute('data-regno');

    //console.log(type+'.jsp?regno='+regno);
    form.action = type+'.jsp?regno='+regno;
    form.submit();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with values passed via onclick function in your code. You need to change it from

```
onclick="delete(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);"
```

to

```
onclick="delete('<%=rs.getString(1)%>');"
```

And check this regno in your javascript function by using either `alert(regno);` or `console.log(regno);`

And one more suggestion. You are using scriptlets in your jsp code. Its highly discouraged. you need to start learning [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) and [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) avoid using scriptlets. Hope this helps..